# How do I not repeat function with setTimeout with if condition?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function that basically gets data from a txt file, parses it, and puts parsed data in HTML tags. This function is set on timeout of 500.

If the data from a file hasn't changed since the last iteration of the function, how can I not put the same data in HTML tags? Because I don't want it to do the same task 417 times lol. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB4kR.png)

I tried this, but it looks like variables are erased after each iteration of function.

```js
function loadTxt() {
    jQuery.get('http://localhost:8000/np/nowPlaying.txt', function (data) {
        var nowPlaying = data.split("\n");
        if (p != data) {
            var p = data;
            var i = 0;
            document.getElementById('track').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
            document.getElementById('by').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
            document.getElementById('artist').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
            if (nowPlaying.length == 5) {
                document.getElementById('from').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
                document.getElementById('album').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
            }
            console.log(p)
        }
    })
    var t = setTimeout(loadTxt, 500);
}
```

Comment: Declare `var p;` outside of this `loadTxt` function, and it will work. BTW, you can put the `split` inside the first `if` block.

Comment: And you need to call the `setTimeout` from inside the GET callback (And inside the `if` condition)

Comment: @trincot where do I declare it? I tried to declare it in other function, but it seems like it doesn't work...
`
function p {
 var p = "";
};

Comment: Not in another function. Make sure it has `loadTxt` in its scope. So either completely global, or in whatever function is a wrapper around `loadTxt`. `function p { var p = ""; }` is so wrong... Just think about it...

Comment: @trincot it made number of requests increasing like it's a geometric progression (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 4096). Did I do smth wrong? [code screenshot](https://sun9-49.userapi.com/c858332/v858332399/21ceac/IrO5BwAgPbM.jpg) [console](https://sun9-14.userapi.com/c858332/v858332399/21cebc/vZ3sZYz-iXY.jpg)

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `var p` is defined inside `loadTxt`, so each time you execute `loadTxt`, you will get a new instance of that variable. Instead, define `p` outside of that function, so when `loadTxt` it will always access the same variable instance.

Some other things could be improved:

- The `split` only needs to be called when you already know the data is different; so inside the first `if` block
- To avoid that you get multiple get-requests that are pending, on what may be a slow connection, don't start the next `setTimeout` before you are sure the current get-request returned a response. So move that inside the `get` callback function.
- Your code does not include the declaration of `t`. As it stands, you seem to implicitly define it as a global variable, and then never use it. So drop it all together.
- Use more descriptive variable names. `p` is quite meaningless.
- As you use jQuery, use it to the full, avoiding the lengthy `document.getElementById`...

Proposed code:

```
jQuery(function () { // Only execute when the DOM has loaded
    let displayedData; // Define only once (this is your `p`)
    // Get a reference to the 5 elements of interest, only once
    let $elems = jQuery("#track, #by, #artist, #from, #album");
    
    function loadTxt() {
        jQuery.get('http://localhost:8000/np/nowPlaying.txt', function (data) {
            if (displayedData != data) {
                displayedData = data;
                data.split("\n").forEach((txt, i) => $elems.eq(i).text(txt));
            }
            // Only launch setTimeout when you have the response
            setTimeout(loadTxt, 500);
        });
    }
    
    loadTxt(); // initial start
});
```

There is one other issue that you can have with your code: if the previous data had five values (so including the album), but the latest only has three, the remaining two values will not be changed. This might not be what you want. Maybe in that case you want the two remaining elements the be cleared.

If so, change your code to this:

```
jQuery(function () { // Only execute when the DOM has loaded
    let displayedData; // Define only once (this is your `p`)
    // Get a reference to the 5 elements of interest, only once
    let $elems = jQuery("#track, #by, #artist, #from, #album");
    
    function loadTxt() {
        jQuery.get('http://localhost:8000/np/nowPlaying.txt', function (data) {
            if (displayedData != data) {
                displayedData = data;
                let props = data.split("\n");
                $elems.each((i, elem) => $(elem).text(props[i] || ""));
            }
            // Only launch setTimeout when you have the response
            setTimeout(loadTxt, 500);
        });
    }
    
    loadTxt(); // initial start
});
```

Comment: I know, I am stupid and you are already tired of me, but...
`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Oh, I knew I was stupid, but not that much stupid. Turned out for me that jquery needs to be connected before any script files in HTML...

Comment: See the addition to my answer with an afterthought.

Comment: Yeap, already spotted this, but as I don't know how `data.split("\n").forEach((txt, i) => $elems.eq(i).text(txt));` makes all the magic, I didn't know how to fix it hah. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

or you can try this (using closure, keep your previous value);

```
function loadTxt() {
    var p = null; // define variable to store previous value
    return () => {
        jQuery.get('http://localhost:8000/np/nowPlaying.txt', function (data) {
            var nowPlaying = data.split("\n");
            if (p != data) {
                p = data; // update previous value
                var i = 0;
                document.getElementById('track').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
                document.getElementById('by').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
                document.getElementById('artist').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
                if (nowPlaying.length == 5) {
                    document.getElementById('from').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
                    document.getElementById('album').innerHTML = nowPlaying[i++];
                }
                console.log(p)
            }
        })
    }
}

var loadTxtWhenChanged = loadTxt();
var t = setInterval(loadTxtWhenChanged, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't vote yet, but if I could, I would have! ♥